# relação entre tabelas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-select

Eu estou com o seguinte problema, eu tenho dois estoques na minha empresa, então tenho dois valores para o estoque, e o registro do estoque fica mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como a imagem mostra, cada produto tem dois registros, cada um informando a quantidade de cada estoque. eu não posso mudar a forma como é feito o registro no banco de dados, e preciso de uma instrução que some os dois, até ai não é tão difícil, o que está fazendo o meu cabelo cair é que eu preciso que esse valor seja informado na mesma tabela do código abaixo

```
SELECT nome_produto AS Nome, Descricao_produto AS 'Marca/Laboratório', principio_ativo AS 'Principio ativo', produtos_precos.Custo_produto AS Custo, produtos_precos.Precovenda_produto AS 'Preço a vista', produtos_precos.precoprazo_produto AS 'Preço a prazo', SUM(produtos_estoque.Estoque_produto) AS Estoque
FROM genius.produtos
LEFT JOIN genius.produtos_precos ON produtos_precos.id_produto = produtos.id
LEFT JOIN genius.produtos_estoque ON produtos_estoque.id_produto = produtos.id
WHERE `nome_produto` LIKE '%ana%' AND genius.produtos_precos.id_empresa = 3;
```

sem a parte "SUM(produtos_estoque.Estoque_produto) AS Estoque" ele da retorna a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando adiciono a parte da soma ele me retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja, ele soma o estoque de todos os produtos que batem com a pesquisa, e não me dá a soma de cada produto

bem, resumindo, eu preciso de uma tabela exatamente como da primeira imagem, mas com uma coluna a mais "estoque" que some os dois estoques de cada produto

Comment: Já tive esse problema para juntar tabelas de preços, onde para cada produto haviam 5 preços diferentes e todos estavam numa mesma tabela. O que fiz foi colocar um LEFT JOIN PRODUTOS P2 ON P1.PROD_ID = P2.PROD_ID. No select puxava a coluna de preço para cada Tabela PRODUTO referenciada: SELECT P1.PRECO, P2.PRECO, ... No seu caso seria o saldo de cada estoque, uma terceira coluna poderia ser a soma do saldo do estoque1 com o estoque2. Acho que isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: @RebertoJunior, sua pergunta não esta muito cara, não entendi onde você quer chegar se é somar todos os calores ou criar uma coluna estoque (mas com uma coluna a mais "estoque")

Answer (score 1):

Roberto, no contexto atual sua pergunta acredito que você possui duas linhas com o mesmo produto e gostaria de somar o estoque contido em ambas, apresentando o valor em apenas uma linha **por produto**.

Sendo assim você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT /* Demais valores da sua consulta, onde todos que não serão agrupados (somados ou contados, por exemplo) 
           deverão aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ao final da consulta*/ 
    nome_produto AS Nome, Descricao_produto AS 'Marca/Laboratório', 
    principio_ativo AS 'Principio ativo', 
    produtos_precos.Custo_produto AS Custo, 
    produtos_precos.Precovenda_produto AS 'Preço a vista', 
    produtos_precos.precoprazo_produto AS 'Preço a prazo',
    SUM(produtos_estoque.Estoque_produto) AS Estoque
FROM genius.produtos
LEFT JOIN genius.produtos_precos ON produtos_precos.id_produto = produtos.id
LEFT JOIN genius.produtos_estoque ON produtos_estoque.id_produto = produtos.id
WHERE `nome_produto` LIKE '%ana%' 
AND genius.produtos_precos.id_empresa = 3;
--Cláusula agrupadora somará o estoque dos produtos dentro do contexto de agrupamento (campos indicados abaixo).
GROUP BY nome_produto, Descricao_produto, principio_ativo, 
         produtos_precos.Custo_produto, produtos_precos.precoprazo_produto;
```

Espero ter conseguido te ajudar.

Comment: eu consegui usando o GROUP BY produto, mas o que acontece é que ele só esconde um dos valores, sem somar o estoque

Comment: O GROUP BY basicamente une linhas semelhantes através dos campos indicados. Se está "ocultando" linhas é porque elas possuem valores identicos entre os campos utilizados na cláusula GROUP BY. Desta forma o valor seria somado entre as linhas que foram "juntadas".

Comment: eu não sei explicar exatamente o que acontece, mas usando o GROUP BY um produto que tem em um dos estoques 5 e no outro 2 aparece só o valor de um deles, mesmo que quando eu tire o GROUP BY da formula apareça o mesmo produto duas vezes e cada um com o valor correspondente de cada estoque